# "glad to know you?" or "nice to meet you"

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

can we use this sentence ?

> glad to know you?

I didn't met this person so I think I can't use "nice to meet you"

Answer (score 3):

It should be "glad to get to know you", but still it sounds quite unnatural and stiff. I'd rather say "nice to meet you" even if you haven't meet this person in real life yet.